# .htaccess is not wroking when remove .php extension from custom php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have project with .htacess file in root for anngualr project and created another folder in root directory which contain file and another .htacess file to hide `.php` from url.Here the url is:
`http://project-demos.com/api/v1.php` Tried every code from
stackoverflow in .htaccess file. Not working at all

**Note**: `There are many question and answer related to this question but they are not working for me`

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Comment: @PrajwalShetty Apache for development and linux for production

Comment: just ensure you enabled mod_rewrite on your system by trying `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache

Comment: Just vaguely mentioning that you “tried everything”, is not a proper way to ask here in this place. Please go read [ask]. You need to show us what you tried, and give us a proper problem description along with it.

Comment: @PrajwalShetty Thank you that is the issue. its done. Please answer it if possible

Comment: 1. what does your http server's error log file contain? 
2. how did you make sure that your .htaccess file is considered at all?

Comment: Please use the `edit` link below your question to revise the question. We cannot really help if you do not provide more _specific_ information. So please add the existing .htaccess file, a sketch of the file system layout relevant here and what result you actually get when trying to use the URL you want to map. _Be precise_ ...